# Lambda concatenation

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, asp.net-core

I tried putting my lambda string in with `+` signs and it won't let me run the code because it says invalid expression!

Top of Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Certifications.Data;
using Certifications.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

namespace Certifications.Controllers
{
    public class Managerial : Controller
    {
        private readonly CertificationContext _context;

        public Managerial(CertificationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

Filter

```
// Approval Filter
string ApprovalFilterBuild = "";

if (approval == "Approved")
{ 
    ApprovalFilterBuild = ".Where(i => i.Approved == true);"; 
}

if (approval == "Revoked")
{
   ApprovalFilterBuild = ".Where(i => i.Approved == false);"; 
}

if (approval == "ALL")
{ 
    ApprovalFilterBuild = ""; 
}
```

Query

```
var certificationContext = _context.INT_CertificationsXREF
            .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationCategories)
            .Include(i => i.INT_Certifications)
            .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationConferred)
            .Include(i => i.RIM_Resource)
            +ApprovalFilterBuild+
            .Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN == i.RIM_Resource.LAN)
            .Where(i => LANlist.Contains(i.RIM_Resource.LAN));


return View(await certificationContext.ToListAsync());
```

Comment: Since when can you concat simple strings with actual code?

Comment: You are trying to concatenate `Expression` with `string`, you cannot.

Comment: Then how would you do this? I am just an intern.

Comment: @TheIntern You don't.  That's the answer.

Comment: See the posted answer. That is the way you'll want to handle it. If you absolutely needed to use strings (ie, you're reading from an external source) you could use reflection to accomplish this.

Comment: Stylistic quibble: you shouldn't explicitly compare to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approval filter needs to be lambda expression rather than a string. This is how you build it.

```
// Approval Filter
Expression<Func<INT_CertificationsXREF, bool>> ApprovalFilterBuild;

if (approval == "Approved")
{ 
    ApprovalFilterBuild = i => i.Approved == true;
}

if (approval == "Revoked")
{
   ApprovalFilterBuild = i => i.Approved == false;
}

if (approval == "ALL")
{ 
    ApprovalFilterBuild = i => true;
}
```

And this is how you use it in the main query.

```
var certificationContext = _context.INT_CertificationsXREF
    .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationCategories)
    .Include(i => i.INT_Certifications)
    .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationConferred)
    .Include(i => i.RIM_Resource)
    .Where(ApprovalFilterBuild)
    .Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN == i.RIM_Resource.LAN)
    .Where(i => LANlist.Contains(i.RIM_Resource.LAN));
```

If approval can be none of the 3 checks then consider assigning default value to `i => true`

Answer (score 5):

All of these Linq methods are returning `IQueryable<>` that doesn't actually execute against your database until you iterate over the results. So you can simply do something like this:

```
//Assuming the type name is INT_CertificationsXREF:
IQueryable<INT_CertificationsXREF> certificationContext = _context.INT_CertificationsXREF
    .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationCategories)
    .Include(i => i.INT_Certifications)
    .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationConferred)
    .Include(i => i.RIM_Resource);

if (approval == "Approved")
{
    certificationContext = certificationContext.Where(i => i.Approved == true);
}
else if (approval == "Revoked")
{
    certificationContext = certificationContext.Where(i => i.Approved == false);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151406/discussion-on-answer-by-davidg-lambda-concatenation).

Answer (score -3):

To be sure it works with both IEnumerable and IQueryable you can use the following code:

```
var certificationContext = _context.INT_CertificationsXREF
        .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationCategories)
        .Include(i => i.INT_Certifications)
        .Include(i => i.INT_CertificationConferred)
        .Include(i => i.RIM_Resource).AsEnumerable();

if (approval == "Approved") 
{
    certificationContext = certificationContext.Where(i => i.Approved).AsEnumerable();
}
if (approval == "Revoked")
{ 
certificationContext = certificationContext.Where(i => !i.Approved).AsEnumerable();
}
var result  = certificationContext.Where(i => i.RIM_Resource.LAN == i.RIM_Resource.LAN).Where(i => LANlist.Contains(i.RIM_Resource.LAN));
```

The "result" variable will have your desired result.

Comment: You should not be using `AsEnumerable` for those operations, as you want them to be performed on the DB, not in memory.  You could use `AsQueryable` if you want to avoid explicitly typing the variable.